# How to list the missing multicolumn statistics?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, statistics

[I have used the database engine tuning advisor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137992/verify-the-importance-of-statistics-database-with-auto-create-stats-works), DTA, in order to improve the performance of one of my databases.

It produced a list of recommendations, mostly [multicolumn statistics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ianjo/2005/11/10/create-multi-column-statistics/).

These recommendations need then to be [cross checked and tested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138114/using-the-database-engine-tuning-advisor-how-do-i-generate-the-scripts-for-the), before applying them in production.

Statistics are [used by the query optimiser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966419.aspx) (whitepaper on MSDN) to track distribution of values in indexes and/or columns.

Inspired by the following reading:

[When is it better to create STATISTICS instead of creating an Index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119025/when-is-it-better-to-create-statistics-instead-of-creating-an-index)

**MY QUESTION IS**

Other than the DTA, is there any other way to find out the missing multicolumn statistics?

Comment: `Other than the DTA, is there any other way to find out the missing multicolumn statistics?` Nope ! query optimizer assumes that columns within the same table are independent. Joe Sack talks about it [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/ten-common-threats-to-execution-plan-quality) and [@paulwhite talks about it here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135041/8783).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Other than the DTA, is there any other way to find out the missing multicolumn statistics?

Nope ! query optimizer assumes that columns within the same table are independent. Joe Sack talks about it [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/ten-common-threats-to-execution-plan-quality)

> The query optimizer assumes that columns within the same table are independent. For example, if you have a city and state column, we may intuitively know that these two columns are correlated, but SQL Server does not understand this unless we help it out with an associated multi-column index, or with manually-created multi-column statistics. Without helping the optimizer with correlation, the selectivity of your predicates may be exaggerated.

and [@paulwhite talks about it here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135041/8783).

> A certain amount of trial-and-error may be necessary to identify the multi-column statistic.